# Magento sales_order_create page don't add product in ordered list

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sidebar

When inside the sidebar in any product select and click on add to order button. The product don't add in ordered list.
What can i do?
Please see this image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a button, it's an image just indicate that the selected items will be moved to the order on "updating changes".

Select the Product's from last ordered items or wishlist items and click **"Update Changes"** button.

In order to add the same functionality to that image, you need to create your own adminhtml theme and make changes to the file:
**app/design/adminhtml/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/sales/order/create/sidebar/items.phtml**

**Line #61**

```
<th class="a-center"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/fam_package_go.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Add To Order') ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Add To Order') ?>" width="16" height="16" onclick="order.sidebarApplyChanges()"/></th>
```

Comment: thank you .but why last ordered items in below button don't working..

Comment: It is not a button, it's an image just indicate that the selected items will be moved to the order on "updating changes". Accept this answer if that sorted your issue

Comment: Yes i accept but i want to add product click on this image

Comment: updated answer, check it

Comment: tick the answer if this showed a way to sort your problem

Comment: @RakeshPatidar: then please tick the answer, to help others users who has the similar issue